# How do I display the elements of a SQLite database in Android Studio?

Tags: android

This is what I've got so far, but it only puts the value inside the database. I need to be able to see what's already inside it but I don't know how. Another good indicator would be to print a toast message with the number of entries on the database.

PS. bonus points if you can help me with crating a new activity expecting an object and retrieving a value when it is done to use it in the father activity. thank y'all.

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

   private static final String TABLE = "Students";
   private static final String DATABASE = "demo.db";
   private static final int VERSION = 1;

   private static final String C_ID = "id";
   private static final String C_NAME = "name";
   private static final String C_MAJOR = "major";

   public DBHelper(Context context){
       super(context, DATABASE, null, VERSION);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

       String creationQuery = "CREATE TABLE " +
            TABLE +
            " (" +
            C_ID +
            " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            C_NAME +
            " TEXT, " +
            C_MAJOR +
            " TEXT)";

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(creationQuery);
   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    String[] tables = {TABLE};

    // prepared statements - check it out for your DB knowledge! yeah!
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ?", tables);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

    // getWritableDatabase
   }

   public void saveRecord(String name, String major){

    // retrieve a reference to the db that we're working with
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    /*
    String query = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(" + C_NAME +", " + C_MAJOR + ") VALUES(?, ?)";
    String[] params = {name, major};
    db.execSQL(query, params);
```

*/

```
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(C_NAME, name);
    cv.put(C_MAJOR, major);
    db.insert(TABLE, null, cv);
   }

   public int getRecord(String name){

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    int result = -1;

    String selection = "name = ?";
    String[] params = {name};

    Cursor c = db.query(TABLE, null, selection, params, null, null, null);

    if(c.moveToFirst()){

        result = c.getInt(0);

    }

    return result;
   }

   public int deleteRecord(String name) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String selection = "name = ?";
    String[] params = {name};
    return db.delete(TABLE, selection, params);
   }
  }
```

Comment: Google "Read sql database android", "intents android", try everything and if you have a specific problem then create a question.

Comment: @Sanoop don't use `inline code` to highlight random terms.

Answer (score 1):

First this one on fragment

```
public class fragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
///
private ListView lista;
private MyAdapter_Amigos adapter_amigos;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static fragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    fragment fragment = new fragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment, container, false);
    lista = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    return v;
}
//Llena arreglo de amigos
public void Lista(ArrayList<Amigo> amigos){
    adapter_amigos = new MyAdapter_Amigos(getActivity(), amigos);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter_amigos);

}


// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

Then on main:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, JSONCallback {


ArrayList<Amigo> amigos;
fragment frag;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    frag = (fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);

}

@Override
public void callBack(JSONObject jo) {
    try {
        amigos = new ArrayList<Amigo>();
        JSONArray arreglo = jo.getJSONArray("result");

        for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length(); i++){
            JSONObject objeto = arreglo .getJSONObject(i);
            Amigo amigo = new Amigo(objeto.getString("Nombre"),objeto.getString("Hobby"));
            amigos.add(amigo);
        }


    }catch (Exception e){

    }
    //Log.d("xx",jo.toString());
    frag.Lista(amigos);
}

public void LoadJson(View v){
    JSONRequest reques = new JSONRequest(this);
    reques.execute("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/my.json");
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}
```

Then on Someone:

```
 public class Amigo {
//ALT INSERT Constructor / ALT INSERT Setters and Getters
public String nombre;
public String hobby;

public Amigo(String nombre, String hobby) {
    this.hobby = hobby;
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getHobby() {
    return hobby;
}

public void setHobby(String hobby) {
    this.hobby = hobby;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
```

Then on my adapter:

```
 public class MyAdapter_Amigos extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<Amigo> amigos;

public MyAdapter_Amigos(Activity activity, ArrayList<Amigo> amigos) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.amigos = amigos;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return amigos.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return amigos.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(view == null){
        view = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row,null);
    }

    TextView nombre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
    TextView hobby = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.hobby);

    nombre.setText((amigos.get(position).getNombre()));
    hobby.setText(amigos.get(position).getHobby());

    return view;
}
```

Then on JSONCallback:

```
  import org.json.JSONObject;


 public interface JSONCallback {

void callBack(JSONObject jo);

 }
```

For last JSONRequest:

```
 public class JSONRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>  {

private JSONCallback activity;

public JSONRequest(JSONCallback activity){
    this.activity = activity;
}


@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
    JSONObject resultado = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        HttpURLConnection conexion = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conexion.connect();

        InputStream is = conexion.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String linea = "";

        while ((linea = bf.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(linea);
        }

        resultado = new JSONObject(sb.toString());

    }catch (Exception e){

    }
    return resultado;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
    activity.callBack(jsonObject);
}
```

This is Fragment 2:

```
  public class fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private ListView lista;
private TextView texto;
private EditText edit;
private Button boton;
private ArrayList<Amigo> friend;
private MyAdapter_Amigos adapter_amigos;


private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment fragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static fragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    fragment fragment = new fragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment, container, false);

    lista = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lista);
    texto = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    edit = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    boton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button3);

    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onClick(View v) {
                                     mListener.BotonComunicacion(edit.getText().toString());
                                 }
                             }
    );

    lista.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    return v;
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}


public void LlenarLista(ArrayList<Amigo> amigos){
    friend = amigos;
   MyAdapter_Amigos adapter_amigos = new MyAdapter_Amigos(amigos ,getActivity());
    lista.setAdapter(adapter_amigos);
}
public void cambiarATexto(String string){
    texto.setText(string);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), vizualizar_datos.class);
    intent.putExtra("nombre", friend.get(position).getNombre());
    intent.putExtra("hobby", friend.get(position).getHobby());
    intent.putExtra("edad", friend.get(position).getEdad());
    intent.putExtra("telefono", friend.get(position).getTelefono());
    intent.putExtra("direccion", friend.get(position).getDireccion());
    startActivity(intent);
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void BotonComunicacion(String string);
    //onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri)
}
```

This is main 2:

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, JSONCallBack {

private TextView texto;
private EditText edit;
private ArrayList<Amigo> amigos;
private fragment frag;
private JSONRequest request;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto1);
    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    amigos = new ArrayList<Amigo>();
    frag = (fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
}

@Override
public void CallBack(JSONObject jo) {
    try{
        JSONArray arreglo = jo.getJSONArray("result");
        for(int i =0 ; i < arreglo.length(); i++){
            JSONObject o = arreglo.getJSONObject(i);
            Amigo amigo = new Amigo(o.getString("Nombre"),o.getString("Hobby"),o.getString("Edad"),o.getString("Telefono"),o.getString("Direccion"));
            amigos.add(amigo);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
    frag.LlenarLista(amigos);
}

public void BotonLoad(View v){
    request = new JSONRequest(this);
    request.execute("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/example.json");
}

@Override
public void BotonComunicacion(String string) {
    texto.setText(string);
}

public void MandarInformacion(View v){
    frag.cambiarATexto(edit.getText().toString());
}
```

And the Viewrs:

```
 public class vizualizar_datos extends AppCompatActivity {


private TextView nombre;
private TextView hobby;
private TextView edad;
private TextView direccion;
private TextView telefono;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vizualizar_datos);

    nombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nombre_vis);
    hobby = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hobby_vis);
    edad = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edad_vis);
    direccion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.direccion_vis);
    telefono = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.telefono_vis);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    nombre.setText(intent.getStringExtra("nombre"));
    hobby.setText(intent.getStringExtra("hobby"));
    edad.setText(intent.getStringExtra("edad"));
    direccion.setText(intent.getStringExtra("telefono"));
    telefono.setText(intent.getStringExtra("telefono"));

}
```